# Proof for Riemann's isolated singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be complex function has isolated singularity at $z_0$.

Suppose $f$ is bounded on some deleted neighborhood of $z_0.$

Then $f$ is holomorphic and bounded on some deleted neighborhood of $z_0.$

Let $h(z)= \begin{cases}  (z-z_0)^2f(z)\mbox{, if z is not z_0 }\\
0 \mbox{, if $z=z_0$}
\end{cases}$

Then Since $f$ is bouned on some deleted neighborhood of $z_0$,
$$ \lim_{z \to z_0} h(z) =0 $$

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{h(z)-h(z_0)}{z-z_0} = 0.$$

So $h$ is analytic at $z_0$. since $h(z_0)=h^\prime (z_0)=0$,

$$h(z)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n $$

so $f(z)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^{n-2}$ on some deleted neighborhood of $z_0$ , By properties of powerseries $f$ is defined at $z_0$ so that $f$ is analytic at $z_0$

[[**I want you guys to be check whether my proof is correct**]]

Comment: Okay. What is your question? Is there something you don't understand in the argument, is that your proof attempt and you are unsure whether it's correct?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry I will edit. I want you guys to be sure whether my proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but your presentation of it may be considered incomplete. That depends on what you can use without mentioning it.

After you've shown that $h$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ with $h(z_0) = h'(z_0) = 0$, you assert that $h$ is analytic at $z_0$. That's true, but it doesn't follow from the differentiability at $z_0$ alone, you need the complex differentiability on a full neighbourhood of $z_0$. Probably you should mention that you have the complex differentiability of $h$ on a punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$ from the assumptions on $f$ and the definition of $h$.

At the end, you mention some unspecified properties of power series. Are you in a position to leave them unspecified (does your audience know which properties these are, and *do they know that you know* which)? If not, you need to specify these properties.

Comment: Your correction is good.